# In pandas, what does the na_action parameter to Series.map do

Tags: pandas

When using [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), what does the `na_action` do? The docs are unclear and I have not come up with an example in which the results are affected by the parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the explanation in the documentation is pretty clear, it's hard to see what's going on if you're using numeric functions that take NaNs as input and return them back as NaN. For anyone else that hasn't read the docs, they say that if na_action='ignore' NA values will not be passed to the mapping function, if na_action=None (the default) they will.

Here's a trivial example showing the difference:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])

s2 = s.map(lambda x: 'this is a string {}'.format(x), na_action=None)

0    this is a string 1.0
1    this is a string 2.0
2    this is a string 3.0
3    this is a string nan
dtype: object

s3 = s.map(lambda x: 'this is a string {}'.format(x), na_action='ignore')

0    this is a string 1.0
1    this is a string 2.0
2    this is a string 3.0
3                     NaN
dtype: object
```

If you have a better example from your own analysis you should consider creating an issue on the [pandas repo](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues), in order to improve the documentation and help others understand.

Comment: Note that it really matters but I'd probably write that as `'this is a string {}'.format`

Comment: @JonClements, I would have done that but I think format will force the NaN to a string. I definitely don't like how it looks, just a forced example.

Comment: Yeah... it'll force nan to a string just like your `str(x)` does at the moment - they're functionally identical :)

Comment: You're right. I wasn't thinking it through...long day. Thanks!

Comment: @shawnheide Want to make a PR to add such an example to the docstring?